# Is there a name for a string that is at the beginning of a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning React Native Reanimated and found out that you can create "special functions" when you include a string with a specific content at the beginning of a function (https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.2.0/worklets/).

I was wondering if there's a way in JavaScript to determine whether a string (with specific content) is included at the beginning of a function. Is that possible? How can you determine the content of the string?

Comment: you mean the `'worklet';` directive?

Comment: The only other string directive I know is `"use strict";`, and to get the string in the function you would need to use `toString` and parse it.

Comment: @GrafiCode yes, exactly

Comment: as @kellys said, you need to parse the function's body in form of a string, something like `functionname.toString().includes("'worklet';")`